# etymology of supernatant

Tags: history-of-chemistry, separation-techniques

Why do we call a solution that has been centrifuged a supernatant? It seems to me that a "natant" should be something that floats (from Latin "natare" meaning "to swim"), and a "supernatant" should be something which lies *above* the natant, not below it. Shouldn't the liquid be called a subnatant? Or maybe a superprecipitate?

Edit: fixed Latin (see below)

Answer (score 5):

It means "the liquid that swims above", from the Latin terms *super* = above and *natare* = to swim.
So it is the liquid that remains on top.

The subnatant would be the liquid at the bottom, in case you should centrifuge two liquid phases.

The term you name, *nato*, means son in Latin.

Comment: OK, so it is "swimming above" the precipitate and not "above" something that is "swimming", such as a floating pellet. That makes more sense!